# Wicket: load image from absolute path

Tags: java, image, wicket

Currently I render my images from my project's "webapp" directory using ContextRelativeResource:

Java:

```
add(new Image("image", new ContextRelativeResource("image.jpg")));
```

HTML:

```
<img wicket:id="image"/>
```

I would like to know how to display images from given absolute path, for example "C:\image.jpg". Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Wicket are you using?

You might want to consider mounting external resources. [Go here](http://wicketinaction.com/2011/07/wicket-1-5-mounting-resources/).

OR use the Image's constructor that takes and ID and a `WebResource`.

Comment: Project's version of Wicket is 1.3.2. Extending WebResource and passing it as an argument to Image constructor did the job. Thanks